# problem in publishing

Tags: web-server, .net, deployment

when i am publishing my .net website on my domain it is showing the directory of files when i open my site ..

anyone please tell me how to avoid this and make my website open mu home page .

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup the default document to be Default.aspx or whatever is your start page. If you are using IIS, take a look at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320051) or something similar ;)

Comment: You may want to turn off 'Directory Browsing' as well so that no one can see your file system.